# Optimising data lookups for Array type column using has(x,y) function in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a column `c` of type `Array(UInt32)` in ClickHouse. I wonder what is the most optimal way for partial data quick lookups using that column and array functions like `has(x,y)`?

Consider value `[1, 2, 3]` in column `c` and query

```sql
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE has(c, 2)
```

(also with multiple conditions like `has(c, 2) AND has(c, 3)`)

When I run the query through `clickhouse-client --force_primary_key true`, ClickHouse complains the primary key is not used for the above query.

*(compared to this query where it is used:*

```sql
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE c = [1,2,3]
```

*That makes sense and is obvious why that happens.)*

What would be the best way (fastest) to lookup data in ClickHouse based on array type column?

---

What I'm currently doing is changing the `c` value to `'|' || arrayStringConcat(cast(c, 'Array(String)'),'|') || '|'` and filtering as `WHERE c_modified LIKE '|2|'`

Comment: I would consider these cases: 1) use [arrayJoin](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-join/) or [ARRAY JOIN](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/array-join/) to flatten data set and then apply your filter 2) [blom-filter index](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#available-types-of-indices) for this column - although there is the active issue related with your case [Bloom filter is still used with not has #7963](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/7963).

Comment: @vladimir thank you. 1) I'm curious and correct me if I'm wrong please but doing array join would not leverage any of CH features to optimise query performance, or if it is not so, what would be the reason it is performant? 2) bloom filter is looking nice, will look into it. I wonder whether my solution to "flatten" the array into string is faster or not